# how to map a checkbox to update the database after submit.

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need to use a the session dataTable email value for the @email and the base from the dropdownlist.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "base";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "base";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

    }


    string str;

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox9.Checked == true)
        {
            str = str + CheckBox9.Text + "x";
        }           
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...);
    String sql = "UPDATE INQUIRY2 set Question1 = @str WHERE email = @email AND Base = @base;";

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session.dt.email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", str);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@base", DropDownList1.base);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for reading the value out of `Session` is wrong, you cannot use `Session.dt.email`.

You need to read the `DataTable` out of `Session` and cast it to a `DataTable`, like this:

```
DataTable theDataTable = null;

// Verify that dt is actually in session before trying to get it
if(Session["dt"] != null)
{
    theDataTable = Session["dt"] as DataTable;
}

string email;

// Verify that the data table is not null
if(theDataTable != null)
{
    email = dataTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
}
```

Now you can use the `email` string value in your SQL command parameters, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
```

UPDATE:

You will want to wrap your drop down list binding in `Page_Load` with a check for `IsPostBack`, because as your code is posted it will bind the drop down list every time the page loads, not just the first time, thus destroying whatever selection the user made.

Instead do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "base";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "base";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Now your `base` value in your database parameter logic should be the value the user selected.

Comment: if(theDataTable != null)
        {
            email = theDataTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
            base1 = theDataTable.Rows[0]["base"].ToString();
        }

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", str);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@base", base1);
IT SEEMS LIKE

Comment: I'm getting an error: Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'email'

Comment: Did you put `string email;` in the same method as your database call? All of the code in my answer should be within the same method as the database logic.

Comment: I made the changes. However, the database is not being updated. any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is your drop down list selection by the user is getting trashed, because you are binding the drop down list on every page load, instead of just the first. See `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Comment: protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox9.Checked == true)
            {
                str = str + CheckBox9.Text + 'x';
            }

Comment: what do you think of the way I'm attaching checkbox to 'x' CheckBox9.Text + 'x';

Comment: That should be fine, because it is just adding to the string value you are storing in the database.